# Base64EncodedString memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, base64

I'm using NSData+Base64 opensrc library found on [githubt](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64) for a project that is due in next month. I just started profiling, analyzing and optimizing, and found out a leak that comes from that code. I have disabled NSZombie and all debugging methods & try-catches, as I have previously found that sometimes they do leak memory.
The exact lines where the leak is pin-pointed is:

```
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString        
{
    return [self base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:0];
}
```

And the disassembly:

```
+0x0    pushl                          %ebp
+0x1    movl                           %esp, %ebp
+0x3    subl                           $24, %esp
+0x6    calll                          -[NSData(Base64) base64EncodedString]+0xb
+0xb    popl                           %eax
+0xc    movl                           +86389(%eax), %eax
+0x12   movl                           %eax, +4(%esp)
+0x16   movl                           +8(%ebp), %eax
+0x19   movl                           %eax, (%esp)
+0x1c   movl                           $0, +8(%esp)
+0x24   calll                          DYLD-STUB$$objc_msgSend   // 100% leak
+0x29   addl                           $24, %esp
+0x2c   popl                           %ebp
+0x2d   ret
```

I have not contacted the author, as I fear it may be my fault for not properly using the library, or just some other part of my code.

When I use the specific method (only use it once), I do so after an encryption routine:

```
+ (NSString *) encryptString:(NSString *)plaintext withKey:(NSString *)key 
{    
    // Convert string-to-be-encrypted to Data
    NSData *inData = [Miscellaneous utf8string2data:plaintext];
    // Encrypt, Encode, Return
    return [[self encryptData:inData withKey:key] base64EncodedString];
}
```

However, I get the feeling that the actual point where memory is leaking is in the method that is being called by method

> base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth

and the exact lines are:

```
outputBytes = realloc(outputBytes, outputLength);
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:outputBytes length:outputLength encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding freeWhenDone:YES];
```

So I guess my questions are:
1) Has anyone observed similar behavior using this library
2) Is it possibly me inducing the leak by using badly allocated strings
3) Anyone know how to solve it, or of another library I can use to replace this ?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have changed the above lines that Instruments pinpoints as the leaking code to:

```
 outputBytes = realloc(outputBytes, outputLength);
 NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:outputBytes length:outputLength encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 free(outputBytes);
```

However, I still get a leak from that line. Is there an issue with malloc/realloc/free in objective C ?

EDIT 2:

```
Bytes Used  # Leaks     Symbol Name
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2       thread_start
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2        _pthread_start
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2         __NSThread__main__
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2          -[NSThread main]
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2           -[Sync get]
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2            -[Request DoRequest]
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2             -[Request encryptMessage:]
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2              +[AES256 encryptString:withKey:]
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2               -[NSData(Base64) base64EncodedString]
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2                -[NSData(Base64) base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:]
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2                 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2                  CFStringCreateWithBytes
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2                   __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2                    _CFRuntimeCreateInstance
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2                     CFAllocatorAllocate
    512 Bytes    5.2%   2                      __CFAllocatorSystemAllocate
```

I don't know if it will help identify whether this is a false warning or not, but by not filtering anything, the culprit appears to be CFAllocatorSystemAllocate:

```
+0x13   calll                          DYLD-STUB$$malloc_zone_malloc
+0x18   addl                           $8, %esp
```

So I am starting to have reservations wether this really is a leak. However debugging on both the emulator & iPad has the same results. ARC is used, and I'm trying to copy objects instead of referencing them.

SOLUTION:
I have found the leak, it was in a method implemented improperly using the wrong kind of cast ( silly me I didn't see this the first time )

```
return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)string,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                               CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
```

bridge_retain here incremented the ARC by one, and thus it wasn't being released, and thats why I was getting the warning. Funnily it was the last piece of code I looked at, before I realized what was wrong. Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried using `MallocStackLogging` then examining stack traces from where the leaked allocations come from?

Comment: @hamstergene No, I haven't, will do it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably right in your analysis that the leak comes from the place where `outputBytes` is reallocated. However, note that the "real" culprit for the leak is that `outputBytes` is not freed in the end. The question is why it is not freed.

If you take a look at the next line, `outputBytes` is fed into `NSString` directly without copying the contents of the string it points to, so I guess that the intention of the author was that `NSString` takes ownership of the `outputBytes` memory block from then on, and it is the responsibility of `NSString` to free it. `NSString` will free this block when its reference counter becomes zero. The next few lines in the code show that the `NSString` becomes auto-released:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
[result autorelease];
#endif
```

If `NSString` is auto-released, then everything should be fine -- the ownership of `NSString` is taken by the autorelease pool, and you should not have to `release` it on your own when you use it. The above code snippet also says that `autorelease` is called only if you are compiling the code without ARC (automatic reference counting). So, I think that the code is correct, therefore the only reason why `outputBytes` could be leaked is because you are retaining the returned `NSString` somewhere and then forget to release it. In other words, the leaked memory is allocated within the library you are using, but the reason why it is not freed lies outside the library and the library itself cannot be made responsible for the leak.

Your `encryptString` method seems to take the encoded string and pass it along to its caller, not changing its reference count anywhere, so you have to keep on looking at places where you are calling `encryptString` to see if there is any place where you are accidentally retaining the string and not releasing it later.

Comment: Thing is, I am using ARC, so I shouldn't have to worry about it being released, right ? I was thinking of trying to change the line where the actual bytes are return, by copying the bytes and then releasing the original bytes, thus allowing ARC to handle the retained NSString that has been returned. Do you think this could work ?

Comment: It could be the case that ARC cannot "infer" when to release the string so it keeps it around forever. This could happen in some cases, especially when messing around with `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` and mixing them with ObjC code. I would try replacing `initWithBytesNoCopy:` with `initWithBytes:` (which makes a copy) and then freeing `outputBytes` before returning from the function.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, but I am still getting a leak from the new line. I am thinking that either outputLength is not correct, or as you said malloc/realloc/free is doing something wrong. As for the referencing, I just went through any piece of code that uses the above code, and made sure that the bytes are copied, and the original object is released. I know its not optimal, but it should avoid retaining an object from what I understand.

Comment: It is unlikely that `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` does something wrong - for me it is more likely that ARC cannot figure out what to do. Also, it is very weird that you are still getting a leak warning at the `realloc` line because there is practically no way for the execution path to avoid `free` that comes right after `realloc`. Are you sure it is really a leak and not a false warning? E.g., have you tried encoding long strings in an infinite loop and watched the memory usage go up?

Comment: No I havent tried that to be honest. What I did try was profiling it on the actual iPad instead of the iPad emulator, but the problem still persists. Im going though any referencing and relevant code again, hoping it might be something I've done wrong. How could I possibly check if its a false warning ? Just test it with various different strings and see what happens ?

Comment: Well, if the leak is within `base64EncodedString`, then simply set up a button on the UI that triggers a loop that encodes, say, ten million random strings into Base64. Then start your app in the emulator, launch the profiler and watch its memory usage after pushing the button. If it goes straight up, you have a leak in `base64EncodedString`. If not, then either there is no leak or it is elsewhere.

Comment: I have found the leak. You were absolutely right, it was retained without being properly released. I have added an edit, but the solution goes to you.